# CSS3 gradients AND background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, gradient

I have a function that when a checkbox's status is changed, it's toggles the class of its parent to give a different background gradient. Click on the Lorem to see it in action

[You can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/f3PZv/).

The problem is that it won't work on the larger box in my example as there is a background image specified for my element, I know that a gradient cannot exist within the same space as the background image.

Is there a workaround for this to add a background gradient to the element? I can't add it to the image as this will be dynamically populated, and not all the images will be the same dimensions.

I don't mind changing any HTML/CSS at all. If it can be done with jQuery, that's great too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradients in CSS 3 is actually just a generated image. So if your browsers supports multiple backgrounds (use Modenizr, to test that), then you can add 2 background images. Like:

```
.multiplebgs.cssgradients .button {
    background-image: url("img.png"), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(247,148,34,0)), to(#dc7703));
    background-image: url("img.png"), -webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(247,148,34,0), #dc7703);
    background-image: url("img.png"), -moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(247,148,34,0), #dc7703);
    background-image: url("img.png"), linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(247,148,34,0), #dc7703);
}
```

Comment: Aha, this works! Now to just add it to the jQuery functionality :) thanks.

Comment: Update: I can't seem to manage to write it into the checkbox change. I expect I'm approaching it from the wrong angle, I should probably set the CSS itself, not change class. But your answer worked as far as mixing images and gradients goes, thanks :)

Comment: it should be possible by just chaning class. That is what recommend to do, it gives you more freedom i styling

Answer (score 1):

You can add another div around the element with the background image and apply the gradient to that.  As long as the image is transparent, the gradient will show through.

```
<div id="div-with-gradient">
    <div id="div-with-image">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
```